# How to build a simple web project which contains html pages and javascript using Visual studio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

Since visual studio added support for JQuery, I am wondering how to create a simple web project that contains html and javascript. I am using VS2010 Ultimate.

Comment: file new project and select website ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to get started with a website with Visual Studio 2010. You can actually use a standard template, by choosing : File -> New -> Website and then in the overview, choose "ASP.NET website" for the template. This will generate everything you will need, to get started.